# how can I rewrite a bash script as a one liner?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to add a gesture command using compiz. There is ***command*** plugin in CCSM, it lets you assign one of the screen corners on mouse move to execute a command.
[image]

I want to toggle **onboard** screen keyboard to hide and show on mouse move to topleft screen corner.

Below script toggles ***onboard*** but it must be a one liner to copy it into compiz command plugin

```
  #!/bin/bash

  wid=`xdotool search --name Keyboard|head -1`
  wstate=`xwininfo -id $wid | grep "Map State:"`

  if [[ "$wstate" == *IsViewable ]]
  then
      xdotool windowunmap $wid
  else
      xdotool windowmap $wid
  fi
```

How can I make it one liner?

Comment: add a `;` for every newline

Comment: Why don't you just save it in a .sh file, make that one executable and then use `sh /home/youruser/path/file.sh` as command?

Comment: You shouldn't need to rewrite it: executable scripts *are* commands, just call the script (by name - if it's not located on your PATH then you will need to use the full absolute path)

Comment: @wawa please don't propagate the "execute a bash script with sh" meme

Comment: @orkoden
I already tried this before posting the question `#!/bin/bash;wid=`xdotool search --name Keyboard|head -1`;wstate=`xwininfo -id $wid | grep "Map State:"`;if [[ "$wstate" == *IsViewable ]];then    xdotool windowunmap $wid;else    xdotool windowmap $wid;fi` with no effect.

Comment: @kenn you don't need `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you need to run a command with a value given by a previous command, you at least have to run two different commands. So first store the value of `wid` and then use a one-line `if` check:

```
wid=$(xdotool search --name Keyboard|head -1)
[[ "$(xwininfo -id "$wid" | grep "Map State:")" == *IsViewable ]] && xdotool windowunmap $wid || xdotool windowmap $wid
```

This takes ventage of the fact that an `if` condition:

```
if [ ... ]; then
   do if true
else
   do if false
fi
```

Can be written as a mere `[ ... ] && do if true || do if false`

In just one line:

```
wid=$(xdotool search --name Keyboard|head -1); [[ "$(xwininfo -id "$wid" | grep "Map State:")" == *IsViewable ]] && xdotool windowunmap $wid || xdotool windowmap $wid
```

Answer (score 3):

You can save your code in bash script with `.sh` extension and provide a full path in the text box.

And your one line bash code:

```
wid="$(xdotool search --name Keyboard|head -1)"; wstate="$(xwininfo -id $wid | grep "Map State:")"; if [[ "$wstate" == *IsViewable ]];then xdotool windowunmap $wid; else xdotool windowmap $wid; fi
```

Here `;` is used to combine multline line bash code in 1 line.

Comment: I swear that I tried it before posting my question, mine didn't work but yours works.

Comment: note the backticks are deprecated. Also, there is no need to say `if ... else`. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah backticks are old way, so removed that, also double quoted `"$(..)"`  for safety purpose. `if . . else` is just an optional here.

Comment: there is no need to quote that `$()`. Check with `r=$(echo "a b c")` for example.